# How do I not download certain websites with wget?

Tags: bash, wget

What I'm currently doing right now is

```
wget www.example.com -m --warc-file="example.com"
```

which works fine for most sites, but for this particular site that I'm saving, there are over a thousand redundant pages, such as www.example.com/eventsf[0]=event_calendar5, while keeping the main www.example.com/events site?

Comment: You might want to read [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page) before you do any more tag wiki edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a relatively newer version of Wget (One released less than 6 years ago), then you can use the `--accept-regex` or `--reject-regex` options to use a regular expression and reject filter the URLs that you really want to download.

Comment: So, for example, I would put `wget www.example.com -m --warc-file"example.com" --reject-regex="events"`, right?

Comment: Pretty much, yes